# beahviour of calling super in mixin

Tags: scala, traits

Below code shows mixin.

```
trait A{
    def a = 1
}

trait X extends A{
    override def a = {
        println("X")
        println((super.a + 3).toString)
        super.a + 3
    }
}  


trait Y extends A{
    override def a = {
        println("Y")
        println((super.a + 5).toString)
        super.a + 5
    }
}

val xy = new AnyRef with X with Y
xy.a
```

output of the code is

```
Y
X
4
9
X
4
```

I've read usage of mixing two or more traits shows stackable behavior starting from the right most to the left and calling super() is resolved using linearization. But looking at the ouput it seems that X is being called twice. Please explain the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new AnyRef with X with Y` is [linearised](https://www.trivento.io/trait-linearization/) as

```
AnyRef -> Y -> X -> AnyRef -> Any
```

so `Y.super` refers to `X`. Since `super` is called twice in

```
trait Y extends A {
    override def a = {
        println("Y")  
        println((super.a + 5).toString) // <-- here
        super.a + 5                     // <-- and here
    }
}
```

`X` gets printed twice.